# Mudar Css com Jquery em vários elementos, um a um

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Tenho um código, que altera o **CSS** do elemento **SELECT** baseado no valor que está selecionado atualmente. O problema é que eu tenho mais de 100 Selects para aplicar esse efeito, mas o meu código só lê o primeiro VALUE do primeiro SELECT, pega a cor e aplica no CSS de todos. Mas meu objetivo é que ele leia um a um e aplique o CSS no Select de acordo com o valor atualmente selecionado.

Abaixo coloquei um código apenas de exemplo. Mas isso é para um formulário PHP, que puxa os dados do banco de dados e apresenta na tela. Portanto, nao da para alterar o CSS direto no SELECT. Preciso que ao formulário ser carregado, ele veja qual OPTION está com o atributo SELECT, leia o CSS dela e copie para o elemento mãe SELECT.

Atualmente, tenho o código abaixo:

```
<div class="form-group">
<select name="label" id="aaaaa" class="checkitens">
    <option style="background-color:red;"selected class="form-control checkitens optionred2">red</option>
    <option style="background-color:green;"  class="form-control checkitens optiongreen2">green</option>
    <option style="background-color:yellow;" class="form-control checkitens optionyellow2">yellow</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<select name="label" id="bbbbb" class="checkitens">
    <option style="background-color:red;" class="form-control checkitens optionred2">red</option>
    <option style="background-color:green;"selected  class="form-control checkitens optiongreen2">green</option>
    <option style="background-color:yellow;" class="form-control checkitens optionyellow2">yellow</option>
</select>
</div>
```

E o seguinte JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      setColor();
      $('select.label').change(function(){
            setColor();       
     });
});

function setColor()
{
    var color =  $('select.checkitens').find('option:selected').attr('class');
    $('select.checkitens').addClass(color);
}
```

E o CSS:

```
.optiongreen2 {color: #25d366 !important;background: #25d3660d !important}
.optionyellow2 {color: #ffc905 !important;background: #ffc9050d !important}
.optionred2 {color: red !important;background: #ff00000d !important;}
```

Isso precisa ser lido e aplicado quando a página é carregada apenas. Pois quando o usuário trocar o valor do SELECT, ele já carrega no novo valor e cor automaticamente, pois nesse caso, adicione um atributo onchange, direto no HTML, ficando assim:

```
<select name="chk_comvenda" id="chk_comvenda" class="form-control checkitens" onchange="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className">
   <option class="form-control checkitens optionred2" value="1" @if($project->chk_comvenda == '1') selected @endif value="not started">1</option>
   <option class="form-control checkitens optionred2" value="2" @if($project->chk_comvenda == '2') selected @endif value="on hold">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Mudei o selector `'select.label'` porque o jQuery não o estava a apanhar. Você vai ter um problema que é os elementos vão acabar por ficar com as class todas das cores e a ultima que estiver no CSS vai-se sobrepor às outras todas. Devia arranjar outra maneira para mudar as cores ou então vai ter de fazer um `removeClass` a todas as outras class's
Demo a funcionar:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('.checkitens').each(function(index){

    setColor(this);
 });

});
 
      $('.checkitens').change(function(){
            setColor(this);       
     });
function setColor(element)
{
    var color =  $(element).find(':selected').attr('class');
    $(element).addClass(color);
}
```

```css
.optiongreen2 {color: #25d366 !important;background: #25d3660d !important}
.optionyellow2 {color: #ffc905 !important;background: #ffc9050d !important}
.optionred2 {color: red !important;background: #ff00000d !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
<select name="label" id="aaaaa" class="checkitens">
    <option style="background-color:red;"selected class="form-control checkitens optionred2">red</option>
    <option style="background-color:green;"  class="form-control checkitens optiongreen2">green</option>
    <option style="background-color:yellow;" class="form-control checkitens optionyellow2">yellow</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<select name="label" id="bbbbb" class="checkitens">
    <option style="background-color:red;" class="form-control checkitens optionred2">red</option>
    <option style="background-color:green;"selected  class="form-control checkitens optiongreen2">green</option>
    <option style="background-color:yellow;" class="form-control checkitens optionyellow2">yellow</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: qual o motivo do downvote?